# Get Maximum Value based upon Multiple Dictionary Objects using Python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary item from which I would like to get the maximum value. This dictionary consists of 2 dictionaries. The following is the dictionary

```
new_f_key: {'previous_f_key': {'1g': ['33725.7', '-70.29'],
                               '2g': ['35613.3', '108.83'],
                               '3g': ['32080.9', '-69.86']},
            'f_key': {'1g': ['8880.8', '-66.99'],
                      '2g': ['6942.6', '114.79'],
                      '3g': ['12300.3', '-70.34']}}
```

I was trying to use the above `iteritems()` and `itemgetter()` but I am not getting the value I wanted.

It should compare all values from the two dictionaries and output the value which is highest and also output the header of that item along with the dictionary in which it exists.

For example, in the  above dictionary, the maximum value is `35613.3` and the key for that is `2g` and it occurred in first dictionary object which is `previous_f_key`.

Comment: Why is everything a string? Is this JSON? Could you just keep track of the maximum separately?

Comment: the values are not string but rather they are float values.

Comment: I'm looking at your question, and they're definitely strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dic = {'previous_f_key': {'1g': ['33725.7', '-70.29'],
                               '2g': ['35613.3', '108.83'],
                               '3g': ['32080.9', '-69.86']},
            'f_key': {'1g': ['8880.8', '-66.99'],
                      '2g': ['6942.6', '114.79'],
                      '3g': ['12300.3', '-70.34']}}

maxx = float('-inf')
for d,v in dic.iteritems():
    for k,v1 in v.iteritems():
        loc_max = float(max(v1, key = float))
        if loc_max > maxx:
            outer_key = d
            header = k
            maxx = loc_max

print outer_key, header, maxx
```

**Output:**

```
previous_f_key 2g 35613.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this. It will handle arbitrary nesting, and it's short.

```
def weird_max(d, key=float):
    vals = []
    for item in d.itervalues():
        if isinstance(item, dict):
            vals.append(weird_max(item))
        else: # should be a list
            vals.extend(item)
    return max(vals, key=key)
```

That said, it relies on type tests, which is less than elegant. I'd generally recommend that you don't do this sort of thing, and either keep a running track of the maximum value, or find a better datastructure to represent this information, e.g. a heap.

ideone here: http://ideone.com/rJ1YZh

Answer (score 1):

Check this out:

```
def maxVal(d):
    if all(isinstance(v, list) for v in d.values()):
        return max(d, key=lambda k: max(d[k]))
    else:
        k = max(d, key=lambda k: maxVal(d[k]))
        return k + ":" + maxVal(d[k])
```

**Testing**:

```
In [79]: %paste
    def maxVal(d):
        if all(isinstance(v, list) for v in d.values()):
            return max(d, key=lambda k: max(d[k]))
        else:
            k = max(d, key=lambda k: maxVal(d[k]))
            return k + ":" + maxVal(d[k])

## -- End pasted text --

In [80]: %paste
dic = {'previous_f_key': {'1g': ['33725.7', '-70.29'],
                               '2g': ['35613.3', '108.83'],
                               '3g': ['32080.9', '-69.86']},
            'f_key': {'1g': ['8880.8', '-66.99'],
                      '2g': ['6942.6', '114.79'],
                      '3g': ['12300.3', '-70.34']}}

## -- End pasted text --

In [81]: maxVal(dic)
Out[81]: 'previous_f_key:2g'
```

Comment: Never occurred to me to pass the current function as a key. I note that this ends up traversing the structures multiple times.

Comment: It is sadly true that it does end up traversing the structure multiple times. I wonder though, if I could write a `max` that would return the key as well as traverse, so that I wouldn't have to call python's `max` every time. Or perhaps this is a good candidate for memoization a la dynamic programming

Comment: If you look at my solution, it traverses only once (kind of - twice at most). The optimal way to do this is to maintain a variable which contains the highest item found. My solution doesn't because I favour concision and readability.

Comment: I did read your solution (+1). But I wanted to offer a recursive solution as well

Comment: My solution is recursive, but yours is a different way (and potentially better in some complex cases, I imagine).

Comment: I see the difference now. I think it's safe to say that they each have their own advantages

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a nested loop:

```
max = -1
maxkey = -1
maxdic = -1
for dic_name, dic in new_f_key.iteritems():
     for key, val in dic.iteritems():
          if val > max:
              max = val
              maxkey = key
              maxdic = dic_name
```

You can probably save the reference to the dictionary as a simple integer flag, I just did this here for clarity

Comment: Nope. Iterating over a `dict` yields the keys. In addition, what happens if there's more than one level of nesting?

Comment: Sorry about the bug, just fixed the first.  What do you mean if there's "more than one level of nesting?"